# "ls" counterpart to "find" operator "-printf"?

Tags: find, ls, printf

The `find` command has a handy `-printf` operator that prints
user-specified metadata for each found file/folder.  Is there such an
option for the `ls` command?

As an alternative, I can feed the list of filenames of interest to
`find` instead of `ls`, but it seems like using a sledgehammer on a
fly.  I already have the files of interest, and I'm not really
"finding" anything.

Additionally, feeding the paths to `find` would be tricky because I
can't just append the desired file paths to the *end* of a `find`
command. The `find` command requires that the paths come *before* the
operators (or "predicates").  For this reason, I can't easily leverage
"xargs".

Thanks to *steeldriver* for his answer.  I think that his use of `stat` would be a solution if I was starting from scratch.  Unfortunately, I have to compare the output with similar information that has already been generated from other systems, specifically using `find`'s `printf`.

Here is some code idioms using `find` that I found to work:

```
# Option 1
Some Command \
| xargs -n 1 -I{} find {} -printf '%p\t%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM\t%s\n'

# Option 2
Some Command | tr '\n' '\0' \
| xargs -0 -I{} find {} -printf '%p\t%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM\t%s\n'
```

Based on *muru's* comment, here is a code idiom that I haven't
gotten working because because my Gnu `find` from
Cygwin is older than version 4.9 and doesn't recognize the predicate `-files0-from`:

```
Some Command | tr '\n' '\0' \
| find -files0-from - -printf '%p\t%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM\t%s\n'
```

Comment: What metadata are you interested in, specifically? It may be available from the `stat` command (or the `stat` builtin of some shells, or `perl`)

Comment: With `find`, I have used `-printf '%p\t%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM\t%s\n'`, i.e., tab-separated path, date/time, and size.  I get many rows of this, which I can send to a file.  It reads nicely into a data frame in many languages.  I have used `stat`, but I want the nice 1-row/file output to feed the data frame ingestors.

Comment: So the GNU coreutils implementation of `stat` will get you close, it just lacks (afaik) the fine-grained control over the datetime format e.g. `stat --printf '%n\t%y\t%s\n'`

Comment: Interesting.  I think I want the fine-grain control because I am comparing with data that has already been generated on different systems.  Currently playing around with `xargs` feeding `find`, but from online examples, I'm having trouble understanding the use of `-I{}` for `xargs`.  Thanks.

Comment: If you have GNU find, then it can read a list of ASCII NUL-separated filenames from stdin or a file using `-files0-from`, eliminating the need for xargs

Comment: @muru: I'm confused.  I'm using Cygwin, which uses gnu utilities.  However, `find --help` and `man find` reveals nothing about `-files0-from`.  [This page](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) confirms that it is a `find` option, but when I try to use it, `find` doesn't recognize that "predicate", e.g., `Some Commands | tr '\n' '\0' | find -files0-from - -printf '%p\t%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM\t%s\n'`.  I also tried with double-dash: `--files0-from`

Comment: I think you need at least 4.9 for that option. Which version of find do you have?

Comment: My `find` version is 4.6.  I need to upgrade.  `findutils` 4.9 is now [available](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=find).  Unfortunately, I am working on a machine that cannot be upgraded.  :(  Thanks for letting me know the problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not with the GNU implementation of `ls`¹ as far as I know, however it's possible with some implementations of `stat`.

For example `stat` from GNU Coreutils, `stat --printf '%n\t%y\t%s\n'` will give you the fields and delimiters that you want although it doesn't (afaik) provide fine-grained control of the datetime format².

If `zsh` is an option however, you could use the [zsh/stat Module](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fstat-Module), perhaps defining your own shell function with the exact output you want:

```
zmodload -F zsh/stat b:zstat

mystat () {
  local f s ret=0
  for f do
    zstat -n -LF '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' -H s -- $f &&
      printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' $s[name] $s[mtime] $s[size] ||
      ret=$?
  done
  return $ret
}
```

Alternatively you may be able to do what you want with a simple perl script using its [lstat function](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lstat), for example

```
mystat() {
  perl -MPOSIX -E '
    foreach $f (@ARGV) { 
      if (@s = lstat($f)) {
        say join "\t", $f, strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", localtime($s[9])), $s[7];
      } else {
        warn "$f: $!\n";
        $ret = 1;
      }
    }
    exit $ret;
  ' -- "$@"
}
```

In any case, that `-printf` is specific to the GNU implementation of `find` (though existed decades before a GNU `stat` command was added). With GNU `find` 4.9 or newer, you can pass an arbitrary list of paths reliably with the `-files0-from` predicate:

```
mystat() {
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] ||
    printf '%s\0' "$@" |
    find -files0-from - -prune -printf '%p\t%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM\t%s\n'
}
```

In any case, note that TAB and NL are as valid characters as any in a file path, so that output cannot be parsed reliably (the timestamp format which can be simplified to `%F %R` is also ambiguous as it's missing the timezone information).

All those do a `lstat()` on the files, so that for those of type *symlink* they report the information about the symlink itself rather than the file they eventually resolve to. To do a `stat()` instead (and report the information after symlink resolution), add the `-L` option to GNU `stat` or GNU `find`, remove it from zsh stat, remove the `-P` option to ast-open's `ls`, and replace `lstat` with `stat` in the `perl` script.

---

<sup>¹ the [ast-open](https://github.com/ksh93/ast-open-archive) implementation does though with `ls -PdZ '%(name)s\t%(mtime:time=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M)s\t%(size)s' -- "$@"` (same syntax as [for the standard `pax` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/pax.html#tag_20_92_04_01)) but AFAIK, that one is no longer being maintained.</sup>

<sup>² GNU `stat` also fails on the file called `-` as it interprets it as meaning to perform a `fstat()` on stdin; zsh's `stat` (which predates GNU's by a few years) doesn't have the issue and has a `-f FD` to perform a `fstat()` on arbitrary file descriptors.</sup>